# Spark program failed to bind to IP shutting down Netty transport

Tags: java, eclipse, apache-spark, hortonworks-data-platform

I have `Hortonworks Sandbox 2.3` and `Spark 1.4.1` on it

I want to run a simple `Spark` application from `eclipse` on `windows 7`, so I wrote 2 classes

```
public class SparkConnector {
   private SparkConf conf;

   public SparkConnector() {

                     try {
                this.initConf();
         } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
         }

   }

   private void initConf() {
                  SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("sparkTest")
                 .set("spark.master", "yarn-client")
                 .set("spark.local.ip","10.24.246.186")
                 .set("spark.driver.host","10.24.246.186");
        
                  this.conf = conf;

   }

   public SparkConf getSparkConf() {
         return this.conf;
   }

}
```

And a Test `Junit` test

```
public class SparTest implements Serializable {

   @Test
   public final void testSpark() {

         try {
                SparkConnector connector = new SparkConnector();
                SparkConf conf = connector.getSparkConf();
                JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
                List<Integer> data = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
                JavaRDD<Integer> distData = sc.parallelize(data);
                System.out.println(distData
                              .reduce(new Function2<Integer, Integer, Integer>() {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                                    public Integer call(Integer a, Integer b) {
                                           return a + b;
                                    }
                              }));

         } catch (Exception e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
         }

   }

}
```

But I get this error

> [2016-05-27 16:56:54,934][ERROR] failed to bind to /10.24.246.186:0, shutting down Netty transport
>
> java.net.BindException: Failed to bind to: /10.24.246.186:0: Service 'sparkDriver' failed after 16 retries!

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Try giving spark.driver.port also in the configuration. From the error messages it looks the port it is picking up is 0 ( though it means random, which is ok). Also, check if you are able to ping this ip.

Comment: @PreetiKhurana , thanks for your comment, I can ping the `IP` and I tried to set `spark.driver.port` , same error .

Comment: Look at /var/log/messages file to see any errors that come there during this time. Also, you can debug further by changing log levels to debug/info.